# Given entropy, re-estimate odds

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, entropy, gambling

An RNG is reported to have an entropy of $2.521$ bits for 6 results. This is biased from a uniform random system which would have $2.585$ bits at maximum entropy.

You want to create a betting game where you test two samples to see if they match. Let's say the standard bet is $1$ credit. The odds should be a $1$ in $6$ chance of a match so the payoff in a totally fair game should be $6$ credits. However, due to the bias, the payoff will not be fair as matching will be at a higher rate than a theoretical $1$ in $6$. What should the payoff be?

---

In solving for this myself I looked at the measured entropy of $2.521$. Knowing that maximum entropy would be $\log_2(X) = 2.521$, I solved for X which gives $X = 2^{2.521}$, $X = 5.739798$.

So the odds must be closer to $\frac{1}{5}$.$739798$ than they are to $\frac{1}{6}$. However when I simulate this, while I am closer the odds estimate of $17.422%$ for a match are less than what the simulation came up with, which was $18.364%$ Is there a better way of determining an estimate without sampling the random stream of values from the RNG? Is there a better way of taking the entropy to calculate the odds? I see that $\frac{2}{2^x} - \frac{1}{6}$ is closer, but I don't know why that works better.

[image: Possible solution formula]

Comment: Is your betting game that two consecutive variates are generated and you win if they match, or that you choose one value and then one variate is generated and you win if that value is generated?  In either case, the fair value is not determined by the entropy alone.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - yes, two variates from the same rng. When I simulated it I sampled with replacement from [1,2,3,4,5,5,6]. So 1-4 and 6 have a 1/7 chance, while 5 has a 2/7 chance of a match. Odds of a match are 0.18364, according to 1e7 games. I know the answer must be simple, but I haven't figured it out yet.